# Proof that $\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^m(x)\cos (nx)\,dx=\frac m{m+n}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{m-1}(x)\cos((n-1)x)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, reduction-formula

How to prove this? 
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^m(x)\cos (nx)\,dx=\frac m{m+n}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{m-1}(x)\cos((n-1)x)\,dx.$$

I know that need to use this formula $\cos(A-B)$ and integration by parts. But I have no idea how to start as the reduction formula is for $\sin^m(x)$ and $\cos^n(x)$ and not $\cos^m(x)$ and $\cos (nx)$

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use integration by parts. Write $\cos(n-1)x=\cos nx\cos x+\sin nx\sin x$ and define$$I:=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos nx\cos^mxdx,\,u:=\sin nx,\,v:=-\frac1m\cos^mx$$so$$u^\prime=n\cos nx,\,v^\prime=\cos^{m-1}x\sin x,\,[uv]_0^{\pi/2}=0$$and$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{m-1}x\cos(n-1)xdx&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{m-1}x\cos nx\cos xdx\\&+\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{m-1}x\sin nx\sin xdx\\&=I+\int_0^{\pi/2}uv^\prime dx\\&=I-\int_0^{\pi/2}u^\prime vdx\\&=I+\frac{nI}{m}\\&=\frac{m+n}{m}I.\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi. Thanks for ur answer, but how do you get it?

Comment: @user754578 I thought my explanation was clear; which part do I need to flesh out?

Comment: From the u = sinnx onwards. Sorry about the trouble. Thank you

Comment: @user754578 See edit.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Sorry I don’t think the answer is correct for the working

Comment: @user754578 Which part are you challenging? Do you think some step is wrong, or have you changed your mind about the result you expect to be right?

Comment: No i think the steps are correct. It seems correct also. It’s just at the end is m/(m+n) integral cos^m-1xcos(n-1)x. And you gotten m+n/mI. So i am assuming I= Integral cos^m-1xcos (n-1)x. Either that or I don’t understand.

Comment: @user754578 For $k\ne0$, $A=kB$ is equivalent to $B=A/k$.